# Waiting animation while download is being prepared and automatic download

Tags: html, ajax, download, wait

Actually a simple task, but I just can't find a suitable solution

1. Data is collected in one form (HTML)
2. After sending, the server needs, among other things, a few seconds to provide the download, a ZIP file
3. During this time, an animation or an overlay should be displayed
4. The download should then be displayed in the browser (e.g. like Chrome at the top right).
5. The page should not be left.

Unfortunately I couldn't get it to work, either the animation works correctly and the download only "flashes" briefly, or the download is displayed properly but the animation reset doesn't work.

I've already read a lot about it here, but unfortunately it doesn't really work, maybe someone can help?

Comment: If you can provide your code, it will be easier to identify the issue

Comment: I tried a variety of things, none of which worked properly. Not sure if it makes sense to just pick one of them?!

Comment: Send one version of the code you have, it's okay if it doesn't work, we just need to see the code you have to better understand the issue

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your efforts!
I have now found a solution:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
       function showLoading() {
           $('#waitinginfo').fadeIn();
       }
       function hideLoading() {
           $('#waitinginfo').fadeOut();
       }

       $("#frmexport").submit(function (event) {

           var formData = new FormData(this);

           showLoading();

           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "testdownload", 
               data: formData,
               success: function (response) {
                   hideLoading();
                   var blob = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/octet-stream' });
                   var downloadLink = $("<a>")
                       .attr("href", window.URL.createObjectURL(blob))
                       .attr("download", "generated-file.txt")
                       .text("Datei herunterladen");

                   $("body").append(downloadLink);
                   downloadLink[0].click();
                   downloadLink.remove();

               },
               error: function (error) {
                   
                   console.error("Error: ", error);
               }
           });
           event.preventDefault();
       });
   });
```

The trick is that after creation, a "virtual" a tag is created in the DOM on which the click event is applied. Since the code is ultimately generated dynamically in an MVC .NET Core application, `type: 'application/octet-stream'` and `.attr("download", "generated-file.txt")` are dynamically placed in the script accordingly.